# MYSQLi PHP connect

Tags: mysqli

Is the following a valid mysqli php connect insert statement?

```
if($mysql_query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,question,securityanswer) VALUES ('$uname','$upass','$selectquestion','$answer')"))
{
?>
    <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>
    <?php
}
 else
{
?>
    <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
    <?php
}
}
```

However I am getting error as "error while registering you..."

Thanks

Comment: hi man, rate me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. There was an issue with the "user_id"  column primary key which was being updated duplicate(0 value) with this error "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'. Upon updating user_id column with auto increment in phpmyadmin, the INSERT query got updated successfully.

Using the below code to check for errors helped.

```
 die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple example:

```
<?php  
//Create the connection  

$con = mysqli_connect("HostName","UserName","password","DBName") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));  

// Write query

$strSQL = "SELECT username FROM MyTable";

// Execute the query.

$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $result["username"]."
";
}

// Close the connection
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you paste the whole block with connection statement?
Otherwise SQL statement looks fine. Excepct you should escape inputs to MySQL

```
if($mysql_query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,question,securityanswer) VALUES ('$uname','$upass','$selectquestion','$answer')"))

Why using if($mysql_query = $conn->query ?
```

better

if($conn->query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,question,securityanswer) VALUES ('$uname','$upass','$selectquestion','$answer')") === TRUE)

Comment: Hi MrGapo, tried using your if statement, however the insert is failing to update the MYSQL DB